# AngularJS unusually high memory consumption

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, google-chrome-devtools

I have an AngularJS application that renders around 200-250  elements . Each of the repeated elements contains inner items , and some of them have nested ng-repeats. On running, the JS Heap memory allocation was around 70MB which caused the webpage on several occasions to crash and if not, definitely affect other open tabs. Batarang suggested that there were around 3000+ Scope items( with $id ). I restructured my directives to a point, there are only around 700-800 Scope items. But the memory consumption is off the charts and there is no marked improvement in performance.
However while running the profiling tool, if i do click on the garbage collector icon, the memory consumption does drop by around 15 MB.
Can anybody tell ne as to how I should be going about debugging such a a problem ?

**UPDATE:**
the following is the directive structure being repeated:

```
<li class="reminder-content">
   <wizards/>
   <editwidget></editwidget>
   <div style="font-size:87%;padding-left:5px;">{{::reminder.time| date:"shortTime"}} <span class="date-particulars">{{::reminder.time | dateFilter}}<span class="date-particulars-date">Reminder was set for <strong>{{::reminder.time | date:"longDate"}}</strong></span></span></div>
   <div class="reminder-body">
      <p class="{{reminder.trip.destination}}">{{::reminder.trip.destination}}</p>
      <p class="pad-top">{{::reminder.text}}</p>
      <p class="pad-top"  id="trav_name"><a href="{{::reminder.traveler.conversationLink}}" target="_blank">{{::reminder.traveler.name}}</a></p>
      <p>{{::reminder.wizard.id | customFilter:this}}</p>
   </div>
</li>



<reminder ng-repeat="reminder in reminders.delegatedReminders track by reminder._id| orderBy:'time'"></reminder>
```

Comment: Did you check if you have memory leaks depending on event listeners? If you attach listeners, you need to detach them when the instance is destroyed (aka `$destroy`). Also, try to have a check if you can use `one-time binding` somewhere... Did you track your `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Yup. The ng-repeat is tracked. Also, I think, I dont understand when to call the $destroy . I have no extra elements being dynamically added or removed from the page apart from the ng-repeat. Also, how can i check for the dangling listeners ?

Comment: it usually happens when you manually register listeners (`angular.element(...).on(String, Function)` and because of that, angular doesn't know how to detach them when it will `$destroy` the element instance.

Comment: But I do not have any elements being removed from the DOM. in sime cases, there might be an ng-repeat over an empty object, in which case i append an empty div with a custom message

Comment: `ng-repeat` redraws on each model change... Also the use of `view filters` affects performance... you should try to serve a well formatted array from the controller directly.

Comment: Interesting, I will update the array in the question so that you can have a better understanding. Also, with every refresh (Ctrl+R) , the memory consumption increases. is the DOM cached ? Or what could be causing this ?

Comment: yes, please, having some part of the code could help people to better understand.

Comment: please, include the `ng-repeat` expression.

Answer (score 4):

`ng-repeat` attaches watchers. You need to optimize all this to 'one-way binding'

Like so:

```
ng-repeat="item in ::$ctrl.items"
```

Also be aware of such constructions inside templates, like `{{smth}}`. Use `{{::smth}}` instead.

Also, don't use `$watch`, `$broadcast`, `$emit`. Always use `'<'` instead of `'='` as bindings.
If you are using angular 1.5+, you can use life circle hooks.

```
$onDestroy() {
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can achieve it:

```
//catch the results returned by $watch
var deReg = $scope.$watch('yourModelValue', function(){

    //your code
});

//De-register watch on destroy event
$scope.$on('$destroy', deReg);

//or you can do it following way if u have multiple watches

 $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
   deReg();
 });
```